# Proprietary Intel driver for processor microcode firmware seems to disable overclocking

Tags: intel, cpu

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Asus B85M-G motherboard with G3258 CPU. This CPU has good overclocking possibilities and I was able to overclock it without hassle. Due to minor issues with hibernation and graphics, I upgraded to 15.04 and turned on “Intel proprietary driver for processor microcode” - then overclocking possibility was gone. After turning this driver off, overclocking was possible again. I am wondering whether it is deliberate action (as suggested, for instance here: http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Non-Z-OC-BIOS-Microcode-overclocking,23682.html) or just  some additional configuration is needed.

Comment: i don't know but the intel guys haven't always been too welcoming of overclocking in the past.

Comment: Definitely deliberate. Officially, the G3258 can only be overclocked on Z-series motherboards.

Comment: Update: on Ubuntu 16.04 (the same hardware - clean install) overclocking works even with "Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs" proprietary driver enabled.